# Is creating Equilateral responsinve triangle with background image in css even possible?

Tags: html, css, svg

And it also should work in IE11.
I've tried:

- Usual triangle-crating techniques using border - **Failed**, no background image.
- Clip-path - **Failed** no IE support
- Triangles with skewing and transforming have to war of having proper percent-based lengths. After ~3 hours of trying to figure it out - **Failed**

My last desperate effort will probably be creating an SVG mask with triangle cut into it and placing it on top of the `<div>` with desired image. But it feels hacky.

Comment: Please refrain from swearing when asking questions

Comment: The last desperate effort should work as long as the image is an SVG image (and not a HTML image). You can then use the SVG file (with the image and mask together) as a background images.

Comment: use a .png image with transparency and set it as the background via css of the div you want to display it in.

Answer (score 1):

One posibility to get it:

```css
.base {
  width: 70%;;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.test {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600);
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  padding-top: 86.6%;
  position: relative;
}

.test:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-60deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
}

.test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(60deg, transparent 50%, white 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="base">
  <div class="test"></div>
  </div>
```